# Term reference with radio buttons + bootstrap tooltip

Tags: 7, javascript, taxonomy-terms, tooltips

In the details of a user I have a term reference that is presented as radio buttons. You can select one radiobutton. The html looks like this:

```
<div id="edit-field-abonnement-und" class="form-radios">
    <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-abonnement-und form-item radio">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-abonnement-und-2" name="field_abonnement[und]" value="2" class="form-radio">  
        <label for="edit-field-abonnement-und-2">Abonnement 1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-abonnement-und form-item radio">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-abonnement-und-3" name="field_abonnement[und]" value="3" class="form-radio">  
        <label for="edit-field-abonnement-und-3">Abonnement 2 </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-abonnement-und form-item radio">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-abonnement-und-4" name="field_abonnement[und]" value="4" class="form-radio">  
        <label for="edit-field-abonnement-und-4">Abonnement 3 </label>

    </div>
    <div class="form-type-radio form-item-field-abonnement-und form-item radio">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-field-abonnement-und-5" name="field_abonnement[und]" value="5" class="form-radio">  
        <label for="edit-field-abonnement-und-5">Abonnement 4 </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I would like to have a tooltip on each div. I can add a javascript file and send some data to the javascript and set the title with the data (I would do this with [taxonomy_term_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7)).

But how can I get a structure like this and make sure the tooltip works?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**

You can theme a field, using [theme suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656):

> field--[type|name[--content-type]|content-type].tpl.php base template:
>
> field.tpl.php
>
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors,
>   listed from the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use
>   the most specific template it finds:
>
> - field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
> - field--content-type.tpl.php
> - field--field-name.tpl.php field--field-type.tpl.php
>
> Note that underscores in a Field's machine name are replaced by hyphens. Also
>   remember to include "field-" in custom field names, e.g: field--field-phone.tpl.php.

Get a copy of the base field theme from `modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php` and copy to your theme's folder, rename and modify as required.

**Part 2**

A better options is to use the [Fences Module](https://drupal.org/project/fences) which allows for greater control over theming your fields.

> Fences is a an easy-to-use tool to specify an HTML element for each
>   field. This element choice will propagate everywhere the field is
>   used, such as teasers, RSS feeds and Views. You don't have to keep
>   re-configuring the same HTML element over and over again every time
>   you display the field.

All of the field tempaltes are in `/sites/all/modules/fences/templates` and correspond to the type of wrapper you have applied to your field.

Like part 1, copy the field you need into your theme's folder, rename and modify as required.